# Как сохранить исходные размеры таблицы Excel при копи/пасте через C#?

Tags: c#, excel

Есть таблица внутри книги Excel, которую нужно достать и поместить в другую книгу. При копи/пасте не сохраняются размеры столбцов и строк исходного файла. Пробовал делать через `PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteColumnWidths)`, но это не помогает. Вот мой код:

```
xlWorkSheet_1.get_Range("C33:AD121").Copy();  
xlWorkSheet_2.get_Range("A1").PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteColumnWidths);
```

Как при переносе данных сохранить исходный формат таблицы?

Comment: Копировать формат по образцу? Записать макрос который должен показать код.

Comment: Макрос как раз и выдает метод PasteSpecial Paste:xlPasteColumnWidths, но через шарп он не работает

Comment: Может быть, кроме `PasteSpecial` нужен ещё какой-нибудь `CopySpecial` (если такой есть)?

Comment: Нет, к сожалению, такого метода нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте [передать числовое значение](https://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;231090) вместо именованного, что-то вроде:

```
xlWorkSheet_2.get_Range("A1").PasteSpecial(8);
```

Список всех опций [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837425.aspx).